# Number of zeros of the zeta function along horizontal lines

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Are there any known results about the number of zeros of the zeta function along horizontal lines of the complex plane? The Riemann hypothesis states that for any such line the number is at most 1, but has this question been investigated? So if we denote by $t_n$ the imaginary part of the $n$-th zeta zero does it always hold $t_{n+1}-t_{n}>0$?

Comment: You're asking whether the Riemann Hypothesis has been investigated?

Comment: The answer to your latter question is that nothing along those lines is known; if that was known, it would imply, for example, that $\zeta(s)$ has no multiple zeroes, which is well out of reach (though there are some partial results using what's known towards Montgomery's pair correlation conjecture). Regarding your former question, perhaps you might be interested in zero-density estimates (for example, see Chapter 10 of Iwaniec-Kowalski).

Comment: Thanks! Concerning my last question, I meant counting the zeros without multiplicities. Denoting by $t_n$ the imaginary part of the -th zeta zero $z_n$ and $t_{n+1}$ the imaginary part of the next zero $z_{n+1}$ with $z_n \neq z_{n+1}$ does it always hold $t_{n+1}-t_n>0$?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: @Alexis: If that is your question, then the answer is also no -- as Amoolya Prasad mentions below, if we knew that, we would know the Riemann Hypothesis since the functional equation tells us that the nontrivial zeroes are symmetric around the half line. I think if you restrict your attention to zeros with $\Re(s) \geqslant 1/2$ and do not worry about multiplicity, even then I think the answer to your question is not known.